# files change format after using "mv" to rename them in bash (Mac)

Tags: bash, mv

I'm using the following bash script on a mac to rename files using a list of file names. It works and doesn't throw an error but when it's finished all the files (which are images) have a question mark following the extension and don't know what application they need to use to open. This does not happen when I manually type in `mv oldName.TIF newName.TIF` into the command line. Help?

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "%s\n" *.TIF | paste - names.txt | while IFS=$'\t' read -r old new; 
do
    mv "$old" "$new";
done
```

Comment: Have you made a dry-run of the script to see what the commands it'll actually use to rename the files? You could replace `mv "$old" "$new";` with  `echo mv "$old" "$new";` - or do `set -x` in the script

Comment: Is your `names.txt` file in DOS/Windows format (see ["Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)), or have some other sort of weird formatting/invisible characters?

Answer (score 2):

I think I might have figured it out. It seems like the problem is running it on a directory that is on a flash drive. When I transfer the folder to my hard drive and run the script it works fine.